# NodeJS - Possibly memory lack?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, out-of-memory

I have run my server application, written in NodeJS, for ~15 days. Then suddenly ~4 hours ago, it crashed and rebooted. Thank to `forever` script, I catch the error below:

```
(node:30317) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 completed listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:30317) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 completed listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [MyServerApp]
 2: 0x126264c [MyServerApp]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [MyServerApp]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [MyServerApp]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [MyServerApp]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, char const*, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [MyServerApp]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [MyServerApp]
 8: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [MyServerApp]
 9: 0xccdc6808506
(node:14681) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 completed listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:14681) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 completed listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

What error could this be? Is it due to my physical server is running out of memory?

My physical server is an `AWS t2 micro` instance, memory pressure is around: `78x/992MB`

Below is the info for my server app, printed by `htop`:

```
VIRT: 1181M
RES: 32816
SHR: 9452
CPU%: 0
MEM%: 3.3
```

Thanks

Comment: This usually means you are creating new objects without dereferencing the old ones. So, the garbage collector won't delete them. Sadly, some memory leaks are hard to track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out 2 major bugs in my server causing this fatal error:

1. A colleague of mine created a script which repeatedly queried the database at some moment. This truly "eats" a lot of memory on the server
2. My code really has a leak, as exactly described in this [great post](http://www.jongleberry.com/understanding-possible-eventemitter-leaks.html).

To enhance the bug fixing, I also setup swap memory, which had not been set up before, as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Blindly increase `max-old-size` is not a good idea until you confirm your code is "leak-free" and your server app does frequently reach the top memory (not the case in my app, which is usually around 40MB and my server still has ~150-200MB free).

For weeks of monitoring the server after we fix the bugs, the server has worked very well, no any warnings nor weird behaviors.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

> Is it due to my physical server is running out of memory?

Yes. It could be due to a memory leak, or just because there are so many concurrent users that you need either more RAM (`--max_old_space_size=<size>`) or more optimized code to handle all of them.

It's safe to assume it is a memory leak, so think of NodeJS as an enemy, as someone that won't kindly tell you where your mistake is. You need to learn debugging, write tests, run them... My friend, if you think it has been tough up to this point, I'm afraid to tell you the worst is yet to come.

Answer (score 0):

I presume (according to the log) that somewhere in your code you are recurrently attaching event listeners to the same event emmiter and this creates a memory leak because each listener needs some more memory. It is likely that it is a bug and there is no need to attach all those duplicate event listeners.

NodeJS has a memory limit but it is a seperate quite sophisticated question and I do not think that it is your case.